# Flutter : How to enable date just certain days in DatePicker

Tags: flutter, datepicker

I have array days list from json : [ "mon", "thu", "fri" ],
How to just show this days on DateTimePicker Option every weeks

```
  final DateTime date = await showDatePicker(
                                      context: context,
                                      firstDate: DateTime.now(),
                                      initialDate: startTime,
                                      lastDate: DateTime(
                                          lasYears, lastMonthQuery, lastDate),
                                        selectableDayPredicate: ??,
                                    );
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> weeks = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
List<int> availableTime = [];


for (int i = 0; i < event.length; i++) {
  availableTime.add(event.data == 'sun'
      ? 0
      : event.data == 'mon'
          ? 1
          : event.data == 'tue'
              ? 2
              : event.data == 'wed'
                  ? 3
                  : event.data == 'thu' ? 4 : event.data == 'fri' ? 5 : 6);
}

List<int> difference =
    weeks.toSet().difference(availableTime.toSet()).toList();

bool _dateAvailable(DateTime day) {
  for (int i = 0; i < difference.length; i++) {
    if (day.weekday == difference[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

final DateTime date = await showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  firstDate: DateTime.now(),
  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
  lastDate: DateTime(
      lasYears, lastMonthQuery, lastDate),
  selectableDayPredicate:
  _dateAvailable,
);
```

first option, thank you